# Laravel 4 login validation issue

Tags: validation, authentication, laravel, laravel-4

I'm having trouble logging in. Even when there are no validation errors to be found, it goes to the else statement block in my postIndex method and brings me back to the login page. Any idea on what the problem is and what do i need to change to fix it?

routes.php

```
<?php    
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@getGuestIndex');
    Route::controller('login', 'LoginController');
?>
```

HomeController.php

```
<?php
    class HomeController extends BaseController {
        public function getGuestIndex()
        {
            return View::make('guests.index');
        }

        public function getAdminIndex()
        {
            return View::make('admin.index');
        }
    }
?>
```

LoginController.php

```
<?php
    class LoginController extends BaseController {
        public function getIndex()
        {
            // Check if we are already logged in.
            if (Auth::check()) {
                return Redirect::action('HomeController@getAdminIndex')
                    ->with('message', 'You are already logged in');
            }

            return View::make('guests.login')
                ->with('title', 'Login');
        }

        public function postIndex()
        {
            // Get all the inputs
            $user = array(
                'username' => Input::get('username'),
                'password' => Input::get('password')
            );

            $validation = User::validate($user);

            if ($validation->passes()) {
                // Try to log the user in.
                if (Auth::attempt($user)) {
                    return Redirect::action('HomeController@getAdminIndex')
                        ->with('message', 'You have logged in successfully');
                }

                return Redirect::to('login')
                    ->withErrors($validation)
                    ->withInput(Input::except('password'));         
            } else {
                // Something went wrong.
                return Redirect::back()
                    ->withErrors($validation)
                    ->withInput(Input::except('password'));
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

BaseModel.php

```
<?php
    class BaseModel extends Eloquent {
        public static function validate($inputs)
        {
            return Validator::make($inputs, static::$rules);
        }

    }
?>
```

User.php

```
<?php
    use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
    use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

    class User extends BaseModel implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {
        protected $table = 'users';
        protected $hidden = array('password');
        protected static $rules = array(
            'username'              => 'required|alpha_dash|min:4',
            'email'                 => 'required|email',
            'password'              => 'required|alpha_num|min:8|confirmed',
            'password_confirmation' => 'required|alpha_num|min:8'
        );

        public function getAuthIdentifier()
        {
            return $this->getKey();
        }

        public function getAuthPassword()
        {
            return $this->password;
        }

        public function getReminderEmail()
        {
            return $this->email;
        }
    }
?>
```

login.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')
<h2>Login into your account</h2>

{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'login')) }}
    <p>
        {{ Form::label('username', 'Username') }}
        {{ Form::text('username', Input::old('username')) }}
    </p>

    <p>
        {{ Form::label('password', 'Password') }}
        {{ Form::password('password') }}
    </p>

    <p>
        {{ Form::submit('Login') }}
    </p>

{{ Form::close() }}

<p>{{ $errors->first('username') }}</p>
<p>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</p>
@stop
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your question and example script the validation is failing.

The problem is likely with the model based validation implementation. You are validating login with registration rules.

One set of validation rules does not fit all situations.

If you add the following lines to your login.blade.php I think you will see additional errors:

```
<p>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</p>
<p>{{ $errors->first('password_confirmation') }}</p>
```

To fix it, you will need to either change the validation rules on your model, or change the validation implementation. These two excellent tutorials show a couple approaches:

https://tutsplus.com/lesson/validation-services/

https://tutsplus.com/lesson/validating-with-models-and-event-listeners/

Comment: Thanks. I assumed it would automatically skip rules/fields in the array that are not a part of the form fields currently being posted. So if I were to use the model and event listeners approach, am I able to keep just 1 set of rules in the model like what I initially wanted/assumed? I just don't want to constantly duplicate rules for every single validation

Comment: You will probably need to create a new set of rules for each mode of validation (login, create, update). While not perfect, I use a variant of the first tutorial. It is difficult to make a one-size-fits-all validation system. If you wanted to be a bit of a cowboy you could remove validation checks on your login form and stick with your existing implementation, although I would advise against it.

Comment: I don't know if you would consider this going all cowboy, but this is what I ended up doing. I created different sets of rules for each mode of validation like you suggested in my User model. As an example:

`$rules = array(
    'email_reg' => 'required|email',
    'password_reg' => 'required|min:8',
    'email_login' => 'required',
    'password_login' => 'required'
)`

Comment: Then in my BaseModel validate method, I did a foreach loop on my rules array and removed any rule sets that are not defined in my posted form.

`foreach (static::$rules as $field => $rule) {
    if ( ! array_key_exists($field, $inputs)) {
        unset(static::$rules[$field]);
    }
}`

Comment: That is an interesting approach and is better than removing the login validation.